# Image not displaying in HTML webpage

Tags: html, image

I have opened this webpage in all browsers, but none of them display the image. It only leaves an empty space in that area, however if you right click on that area then the typical menu appears. When I choose open image in new tab, it doesnt display anything at all, in spite of the picture being stored in the correct folder

The code used here is,

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/advert1.jpg" width="192" height="253" alt="">
</td>
```

However if I replace the path as

```
"C:/wamp/www/images/advert1.jpg"
```

Then it shoes a small box in that area, yet the picture is not displayed

Comment: When you open the image in a new tab, what is in the address bar for that tab?

Comment: This is the address, http://localhost/headered/images/advert1.jpg
However I have even tried using "headered/images/advert1.jpg" but it doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your syntax (that I can see). Make sure that the image exists at that path and that is has the correct unix permissions (assuming that you are running a unix based system). Any images much be readable by the world, not just you.

Comment: This is a Windows machine and I am running it in WAMP server. As I mentioned the image is stored in the correct folder and when I give the complete path it displays a small box around that area (No X either) It doesnt give any error message that image cannot be displayed, nothing'

Comment: Have you tried opening the image in a program other than a web browser? Maybe the image is corrupted or something like that.

Comment: I have no idea what happened there but it works! but after I renamed that file and made it into GIF its displaying correctly! Wierd because some other images are also in JPG and have no problem. Thanks matzahboy

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\ then put whatever your profile name is and wherever the image is saved .png or .jpg

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me first, so I again saved the file on another location in the computer, then the browser starts displaying the image.
try saving your file and the image on a separate file and save them on a different location.